# enable and disable tab in ajax tabcontainer in button click

Tags: asp.net, ajax, tabcontrol, tabcontainer

I am using ajax tab container in asp.net app, having 2 tabs 1.first tab having gridview , 2. second tab having add new item form.
on rowcommand click i am getting all values in second tab, on click of edit i enable all the controls to edit.
During this i want to restrict user to navigate to first tab until he clicks on *GotoGrid* button.
how to implement this?
if i use

> tab_name.enable=false;

it gets disabled even all the buttons and the controls.
please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="disabledPaneIndex" />
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server" ID="Accordion1" >
     <Panes>
          <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="Pane1" >
               <Header>
                    Pane 1
               </Header>
               <Content>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SwitchToPane2Button" Text="Go To Pane2" OnClick="SwitchToPane2Button_Click" />
               </Content>
          </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
          <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="Pane2">
               <Header>
                    Pane 2
               </Header>
               <Content>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SwitchBackButton" Text="Go Back" OnClick="SwitchBackButton_Click" />
               </Content>
          </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
     </Panes>
</ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```

server code:

```
protected void SwitchToPane2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Accordion1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    disabledPaneIndex.Value = "0";
}

protected void SwitchBackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    disabledPaneIndex.Value = string.Empty;
    Accordion1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

JavaScript (place right after the `ScriptManager` control

```
function pageLoad() {
     var accordion = $find("<%= Accordion1.ClientID %>_AccordionExtender");
     accordion.remove_selectedIndexChanging(selectedIndexChanging);
     accordion.add_selectedIndexChanging(selectedIndexChanging);
}

function selectedIndexChanging(sender, args) {
     var disabledIndexValue = parseInt($get("<%= disabledPaneIndex.ClientID %>").value);
     if (!isNaN(disabledIndexValue) && args.get_selectedIndex() === disabledIndexValue) {
          args.set_cancel(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: thank for reply, i have one more doubt!

my container name is like this...
'        <asp:TabContainer ID="Tab_Client_Holiday" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" Height="100%" Width="100%" CssClass="fancy" ForeColor="Black">'


how to get <ajaxtoolkit> ?

Comment: That's just a prefix. You absolutely free to use any custom prefix to register custom server controls. For example you can use `imTheMostCoolAspNetDeveloper:Accordion`. Just change `ajaxtoolkit` to `asp` in this particular case